# The best way to avoid generic ForeignKey in django

Tags: sql, django

I have `Picture` model which contains different link to images. I also have `People` and `Car` models that may have one or more images. That means that certain pictures can belong to an object in `Car` or `People` model.

I try to make `ForeignKey` but one of the field (car_id or people_id) will be empty.

I can't create an abstract model and make `ForeignKey` from `Picture`

The last solution that I know is `genericForeignKey` but it seems to complex for such trivial task.

Is there are a best way to solve the problem?

Comment: What makes you say that a generic foreign key is too complex? This is exactly what it is for, and it is not too hard to set up once you understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @solarissmoke, The quote from "Two scoops of Django":

"Reduction in speed of queries due to lack of indexing between models.
Danger of data corruption as a table can refer to another against a non-existent record."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:
I created another model called `Album` that has only `id`

```
class People(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  album = models.OneToOneField(Album)

class Car(models.Model):
  horse_power = models.IntegerField()
  ablum = models.OneToOneField(Album)

class Picture(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```